# Costume of sprite in Scratch doesn't change

Tags: mit-scratch

[image]

I am trying to make a simple game in Scratch, but I can't figure out why my costume isn't changing.

You can see what i tried in the photo but it isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

I found the error. I thought by 5 in the distance we were referring to a distance proportional to the coordinates, but apparently, the distance is in the metrics of pixels. Still though later the costume doesn't change back to shark-a.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: You are making the costume switch when the distance to the donut is > 5. There is no wait block. If you add wait blocks in between the costume change, it will work. I would try 0.1 to 1 seconds.